# How do I set the global PATH environment variable on OS X?

Tags: mac-osx, path

I'd like to append to the global PATH environment variable on OS X so that all user shells and GUI applications get the same PATH environment.

I know I can append to the path in shell startup scripts, but those settings are not inherited by GUI applications.

The only way I found so far is to redefine the PATH environment variable in **/etc/launchd.conf**:

```
setenv PATH /usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/my/path
```

I couldn't figure out a way to actually append to PATH in `launchd.conf`.

I'm a bit worried about this method, but so far this is the only thing that works. Is there a better way?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/347286

Comment: For Yosemite and later, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385934/setting-environment-variables-via-launchd-conf-no-longer-works-in-os-x-yosemite/26586170#26586170

Comment: None of the answers here address the OP's question. But the comment here by thSoft is right on the money! Maybe this should be merged or linked to that referenced question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385934/setting-environment-variables-via-launchd-conf-no-longer-works-in-os-x-yosemite/26586170#26586170

Answer (score 76):

[palmer's GUI information](https://serverfault.com/questions/16355/how-do-i-set-the-global-path-environment-variable-on-os-x/16736#16736) is correct, but there is a more maintainable way to modify the path seen by the shell. Like [mediaslave said](https://serverfault.com/questions/16355/how-do-i-set-the-global-path-environment-variable-on-os-x/62109#62109), you can edit `/etc/paths`, but even better you can drop a text file in `/etc/paths.d/` that has a path in it and all shells will construct the path correctly.

For example, on my system:

```
$ cat /etc/paths
/usr/bin
/bin
/usr/sbin
/sbin
/usr/local/bin
$ ls /etc/paths.d
X11       git      postgres
$ cat /etc/paths.d/postgres
/Library/PostgreSQL/8.4/bin
$ echo $PATH
/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:/Library/PostgreSQL/8.4/bin:/usr/X11/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin
```

Comment: Nice, thanks!  Note: this requires you to log out and log back in before it works.

Comment: @weronika: I found it was sufficient to quit and re-launch `X11` (less painful than logging completely out).  I didn't try it in `Terminal`.

Comment: I was referring to Terminal - you're right, I forgot to specify.

Comment: This is good to know, but it does NOT answer the OP's question in that this mechanism does not apply to GUI apps. The OP was looking for a *unified* solution that allows him to *append* to the default `$PATH`.

Comment: what do you mean by "my system" here, @cogg? Aren't we all using OS X here? Sorry but I'm still new to OS X. I'm using OS X 10.7

Comment: Quite 7 years later. This does not work for me.

Answer (score 50):

## `/etc/launchd.conf`

The `launchd.conf` file is **the only complete solution that will work for both command line and GUI applications on [OS X v10.8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OS_X_Mountain_Lion) (Mountain Lion) and [v10.9](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OS_X_Mavericks) (Mavericks), one that will work with GUI and console applications, for all users.

```
sudo touch /etc/launchd.conf
sudo nano /etc/launchd.conf
```

Add

```
setenv PATH /usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin
```

In the example above I added `/usr/local/bin` to the default environment values for PATH.

Keep in mind that this file is not a script and you do not have the option to use substitutions. Also, to have these applied you need to reboot.

Remember, all others are only partial solutions:

- `environment.plist` does not work for applications launched via Spotlight.
- `/etc/paths` - only for console
- `/etc/csh.cshrc` or `/etc/bashrc` - only for some shells

This answer is based on the same question from *[Setting environment variables on Mac OS X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/135688)*.

Comment: Great finding, but the question already talks about *launchd* and is asking on how to **append** to the path in it.

Comment: Did you really add a comment to the original question pointing to yourself as "the real answer"?

Comment: It's implied by your - helpful - answer, but just to spell it out: the OP's desire to *append* to the default path is not supported, because you can't reference other environment variables in `/etc/launchd.conf`.

Comment: It isn't global--the command line environment will discard this when  /etc/profile calls path_helper and rebuilds PATH from /etc/paths and /etc/paths.d/

Comment: I'm on OS X 10.8, but creating `/etc/launchd.conf` and rebooting doesn't seem to change `$PATH`. I would like to move `/usr/local/bin` before `/usr/bin/`, but `/etc/path` and `/etc/paths.d` seem to take precendence...

Comment: according to http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/106355/setting-the-system-wide-path-environment-variable-in-mavericks, this no long works for Yosemite or later

Answer (score 8):

You're going to have to set it on a shell-by-shell basis; Bash and csh-like shells do not share the same configuration files and syntax for adjusting the PATH.

Trying to do this in `launchctl` will not work, because environment variables are set on login; they do not exist system wide in Unix outside of a shell session.

So you're going to want to add

```
setenv PATH "$PATH:/add/my/extra/path"
```

to `/etc/csh.cshrc` and

```
export PATH="$PATH:/more/paths:/
```

to `/etc/bashrc`.

If you want environment variables in GUI applications, that's more complicated. You have to create a `.MacOSX/environment.plist` file in each user's home directory. The `.MacOSX` directory will likely not exist by default, so you'll have to create it.

The format of the file is like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple Computer//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>

    <key>PRINTER</key>
    <string>myprinter</string>

    <key>PATH</key>
    <string>/path/to/thing/I/need</string>

    <key>DISPLAY</key>
    <string>0:1</string>

</dict>
</plist>
```

More on the `environment.plist` [is on Apple's site](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPRuntimeConfig/Articles/EnvironmentVars.html).

Comment: But the settings do take effect when set in /etc/launchd.conf... Hmmm... /me is confused.

Comment: Really?  What environment variable are you setting there?

Comment: Just an update as of OS X 10.8: the `~/.MacOSX/environment.plist` approach is no longer supported and there's no substitute at the user level. System-wide you can use `/etc/launchd.conf` (and there's a per-*.app solution).

Comment: Does not answer OP's questions.

Answer (score 3):

You can edit your global path by adding lines to `/etc/paths`, one path per line.

`sudo nano /etc/paths` should get you there.

Comment: This is good to know, but it does not answer the OP's question in that this mechanism does not apply to GUI apps.

Answer (score 1):

Have you had a look at the man page for the `path_helper` command-line utility on OS X? I answered a [somewhat related question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/347286/what-are-the-various-files-that-could-have-path-declarations-for-os-x-terminal-in/347292#347292) that I think you may find helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if anyone covered **the simplest** and most **elegant** way. At least on [Mac OS X v10.6](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mac_OS_X_Snow_Leopard) (Snow Leopard).

Messing with the `[/etc/|~/.]` of `[profile|bashrc]` files may work, but it's somewhat of a hack. The `/etc/paths.d/` directory is the way to go:

- Sudo into your favorite editor.
- Create a new file named `*name*` (just don't name it something that's already in there) in `/etc/paths.d/` with a path per line:

  ```
  /usr/X11/bin
  /Developer/usr/bin
  ```
- Then add

  ```
  eval '/usr/libexec/path_helper -s`
  ```

  to `profile` or `bashrc`, and you should be good to go.

Comment: This is good to know, but it does not answer the OP's question in that this mechanism does not apply to GUI apps.

Comment: Is the file name literally `*name*`? Or do you mean just `name`?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if launchd accepts this, but try:

```
setenv PATH "$PATH:/my/path"
```

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't work. It doesn't look like launchctl has access to environment variables that easy. There is a command to get environment variables, but there's absolutely no documentation on how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you'd use `/etc/launchd.conf` as opposed to `/etc/profile` - but I'm no expert in Mac OS X - I believe you in that I'm sure it works, but `launchd` is the Mac OS X implementation/replacement for `init` - Mac OS X confuses me.

Anyway, `setenv PATH "$PATH:/more/paths:/and/more/paths"` will work (tcsh), and the bourn shell equivalent is `export PATH="$PATH:/more/paths:/and/more/paths"` - I have no idea how `launchd` is related to a particular shell either.

I think I've asked more questions then I've answered =)

Comment: /etc/profile path settings are not seen by any of the OS X GUI apps. That only applies to bash. I want all applications to get the new path setting.

Comment: Unix? Sure, it's unix. I mean, sorta. Yea, we broke stuff that's worked for 30 years, but it's still unix! /sigh