# How to set PATH variable on Mac OS so that even non-terminal apps see it?

Tags: mac-osx, path, emacs

I need to add a directory to my PATH variable on Mac OS.

I added it in `.bash_profile` and `.profile`, and that works for the terminal.

But Emacs (http://emacsformacosx.com) still does not use the new PATH variable. (I'm trying to run latex from emacs, but it's not finding the command in my `/usr/local/bin`, which I'm trying to add to the PATH ...)

I even logged out and back in, but still no luck.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Enter your finding as an answer. In 48 hours you can mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 2):

The "correct" way to add search paths on OSX is to add a file to `/etc/paths.d/`.

Create a file called `/etc/paths.d/local` and put `/usr/local/bin` inside it.

I'm not certain that Emacs-for-OSX will pick it up from here, but it should.

Comment: This does not work for me. What ended up working was putting it in a `.MacOSX/environment.plist` file, see my update.

Answer (score 1):

The suggestion given [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/16355/how-to-set-global-path-on-os-x/16736#16736) works:

Add it to a `.MacOSX/environment.plist` file in the prescribed XML format, and Emacs will work fine.

*(Found this myself eventually.)*